# How to show weather forecast in European format in iOS?

Tags: ios, weather.app

Currently the iOS built-in Weather app shows temperature forecast in the American format (mixed this day/next day).

Is it possible to set it to the European format (forecast grouped by days)?

Example:

currently it shows:

```
Friday 27/9
Saturday 12/4
```

It means (it took me a while to figure out) that the max temperature on Friday will be 27 and the lowest on Saturday 9, also highest on Saturday is forecast to be 12 and the lowest for Sunday 4.

I wish to see it in this format:

```
Friday x/27
Saturday 9/12
Sunday  4/y
```

Or should I look for another weather app? (I already have [The Weather Channel: Forecast](https://itunes.apple.com/si/app/the-weather-channel-forecast/id295646461), but is uses the same American format)

PS: I use Celsius as unit in the question, although it is not relevant.

Comment: Have you tried changing the iPhone's region setting to your area?

Comment: @fsb It is already set to my area.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your region settings?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you consider to be "European format". Today will have a high of 14 [this afternoon] & a low of 3 [overnight]. That's "14 3", same as Apple & the BBC show it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be wrong saying

> It means (it took me a while to figure out) that the max temperature on Friday will be 27 and the lowest on Saturday 9

The weather app show you a forecast of 24h on your screen, so if you open it at 9am it will show you the higher temperature and the lowest one until 9am tomorrow (and probably the higher will be during afternoon and the lowest during sunrise). As a forecast, the app doesn´t care about the past.
Afterward, I believe that the rest of the week will also show the same 24h (in this case from 9am to 9am next day)

Plus, like Tetsunjin commented, the European format use 24h format and celcius ; the American format use 12h format and fahrenheit.

Comment: Not really. If one opens the hourly forecast, it is obvious that "the low of the day" is the one from the next day morning. Except in european sites, where it is "the low on the same day". I can post screenshots (they are public data anyway, everyone can check).

Comment: Well, I was speaking about the iOS built-in Weather app, wich is forecasting weather, not site that give proper weather of one day exclusively.

Comment: How would you define 'low on the same day'? Considering today will end before the lowest temperature will be reached overnight, so the actual low will be strictly 'tomorrow' whether you're awake by then or not. As a forecast, it would be pointless to tell you what the temperature fell to last night, or even what it will be by midnight of today.

Comment: @EddGrowl It is the same in app. It behaves as an US web site. I gave websites as an example, as they can be easily viewed, unlike apps, for which I have no example of "european" format.

Comment: @Tetsujin 'low on the same day' is "lowest temperature on the named day". I deliberately wrote an example a few days in future, to avoid the "half it already passed" argument. Today is friday. Let us look at the forecast for monday. There is no reason to write the highest temp on monday and lowest on tuesday under the label "monday". (or even if there is, I am looking for the option to choose the format I prefer, which is how europeans do it)

Comment: I'm European & I don't understand how you are defining "Monday" You do realise that days tend to start when we're all asleep? So any definition of 'tomorrow' is necessarily inaccurate because of that. Tonight's low will be 4C... does it matter if it's actually technically still Friday or early Saturday? It's just 'before I get up'. The low from 9 hours ago or more is completely unimportant to a forecast, by definition.

Comment: @Tetsujin  monday is from 00:00 to 23:59, I thought it is obvious.

Comment: So you want the forecast to tell you the the low will be 9° & then be surprised to see frost when you wake at 7am, which is, of course now Tuesday... & it got colder since midnight?